# If $Z\sim N(0,1)$, find distribution of $Z^2$ using moment generating functions

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

Let $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=Z^2$. Find the distribution of $Y$ using moment generating functions.
\begin{align*}
M_Y(t)&=E(e^{Z^2t})\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{z^2t}f_Z(z)\ dz\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{z^2t}\cdot e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\ dz\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{z^2(t-\frac12)}\ dz
\end{align*}
I'm not sure how to simplify this or find which distribution this is

Comment: in general, to recover the pdf from the mgf, you can either take an inverse laplace transform or recognize it as being equal to the mgf of a known distribution

Comment: The question linked by StubbornAtom answers the first part of your question.  For the second part, do you recognize the distribution of $Y$ given $$M_Y(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t}}, \quad t <\frac{1}{2}?$$

Comment: Yes this answers the first part but i'm not sure which distribution has this moment generating function?

Comment: @sigma Maybe take a look at a list of common MGFs to help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Examples

Comment: Google 'square of standard normal distribution'.

Comment: Oh I see, $Y=Z^2\sim$ Gamma$(1/2,2)$